# Chrome extension messaging with XMLhttprequest object fires more then once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Im developing a chrome extension (developer tool) and injection some code directly in the website:

```
(function (send) {

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (method, url, async) {


        send.call(this, method, url, false);

        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('data', {

            detail: {
                data_1: 'hello world'
            }

        }));

    };


})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

This code listens for GET requests from the websites and then sends a message (through the content script) to my message script. The problem is that the messages pile up. So on the first request I get 1 message, on the second I get 2 messages resulting in 3 messages total, then 6 and so on. Why does it pile up that way?

The message goes through the "content" script:

```
document.addEventListener('data_2', function(e) { 

sendObjectToDevTools({data_3: e.detail.data_1 });

});
```

And then finally received by "message" script:

```
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {

...

if (message.data_3) {

//do stuff

...
```

PS. This is not an iframe problem or scripts being loaded more than once.

Comment: How are you setting your event handler?  In jquery (or vanilla js for that matter), if you set an event handler more then once, it runs more then once, so you usually have to remove the old event handler manually before adding a new one.  This would cause this sort of behavior.

Comment: @Brian Are you talking about the part in my code that says `//do stuff` ? Because in that case Im actually doing a POST to my server. But it doesn't matter what I do there. If I do a simple `alert('hello');` it will have the same behavior. It will alert multiple times.

Comment: I think its a bug in chrome api with XMLHttpRequest.....